# Azure Webapp (windows) : URL rewrite to external links returns ERROR

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I noticed that over previous few days/weeks URL rewrite linked to external links stopped working

Every single link now returns an error:
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Azure Webapp is live for 3-4 years
But over the past few days/weeks there's an error.
No changes, no upgrades, nothing done on portal for ages.

THIS WORKS:

```
<rule name="NAME1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^Match1URL/?(.*)" />
<action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/another-url/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

THIS ALSO WORKS:

```
<rule name="NAME2" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^Match2URL/?(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/another-url/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

BUT THIS RETURNS ERROR:

```
<rule name="NAME" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^MatchURL/?(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="https://example.com/another-url/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

**UPDATE:** 
after I enabled all diagnostic logs , restarted app it works :-) 
also it works after disabled all the logging

strange, but over the past 1-2 hours I did some 20 restarts after each change to web.config file to be sure the changes were accepted ... but no luck

any idea about this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite action should be a relative path, see the [documentation](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rewrite_action):

```
A substitution string must always specify the URL path
```

This [happened](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/01/30/the-resource-you-are-looking-for-has-been-removed-had-its-name-changed-or-is-temporarily-unavailable-404-63-0/) on an ASE, it is possible to configure dynamic IP security on the multi-tenant environment and if your rule is hit then you would get the same.  For sure you can configure this on a stand-alone IIS server.

Comment: Any update now? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)